# Delphi XE2: InputQuery display box width is over-sized

Tags: delphi, vcl

When trying to using a multi-line APrompt: i.e.

```
sPrompt := 'some text' + #13#10#10 + 'some more info...' + #13#10 +
           'Blah, Blah' + #13#10#10 + 'What is your input?';
```

The InputQuery function takes the string as an array of string,
 it calculates the MaxWidth for the Form according to the longest string in the array.

In the above example the InputQuery form is calculated by the length of the string, which is about 50 characters. Though the longest line is a fraction of that.

The result is a very wide InputQuery box being displayed with lots of empty space.
Does not look very professional.

When I try to create an array of string to hold each line:

```
var saPrompt: array of string;
    sInputString: String;
Begin
   SetLength(saPrompt,4);
   saPrompt[0] := 'some text' + #13#10#10;
   saPrompt[1] := 'some more info...' + #13#10;
   saPrompt[2] := 'Blah, Blah' + #13#10#10;
   saPrompt[3] := 'What is your input?';
   sInputString := '???';

   If InputQuery('I Need Input?',saPrompt,sInputString) then
```

I can not compile due to No Overload function exists to take these parameters of the InputQuery function.
I have looked at the Overload InputQuery functions in the Vcl.Dialogs Unit but can not get it to work.

Does anyone know the correct syntax to use the InputQuery Function with a multi-line prompt?

I am using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2 - Delphi

Thanks in advance for any 'helpful' response.

Comment: You can compile and run it if you pass it an array (sInputString: array of string), but this not what you want, it would produce 4 input fields.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood the query box's layout. Pass it *'What is your input?';* and you'll have the exact same width with your top most 'sPrompt'.

Comment: Yeah! thanx Sertac, I get the array of string idea now (the input string needs to be an array also). and yes not what I want, I only want a single input, I just like to have more information for the user than "Enter a name: " , I will just write my own runtime input form :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetPassword:string;
var 
  saPrompt,saVal: array of string;
begin
 SetLength(saPrompt,1);
 saPrompt[0] := #30'Enter password';
 SetLength(saVal,1);
 saVal[0] := '??????';
 if InputQuery('Password',saPrompt,saVal) 
    then result:=saVal[0] else return:='';
end;
```

This code works in Delphi XE2. Haven't tried previous versions.
I would have thought this is self-explanatory (if you have some Delphi experience).
Cheers
Christoph

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..